# What is the significance of the binary sequence in this trophy image?

Tags: saints-row-iv

I received a trophy called "[Ooo A Piece of Candy!](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/saints-row-4/achievement/80182-Ooo-A-Piece-of-Candy-.html)" while playing Saints Row IV: Re-Elected on my PlayStation 4.

The achievement says:

> Found 100 Data Clusters in virtual Steelport. There are so many more...

Here is the trophy image:

[image]

I know this to be some form of binary, but for the life of me, I don't know any binary.

What does this binary sequence represent? Is there any significance to the sequence of numbers, either within the game world itself, or related to the game?

Any helpful insights and information into this would be great full as this question is on topic, however, the answer is needed and can currently be discussed at the chat box.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42812/discussion-on-question-by-warrenwoodhouse-what-is-the-significance-of-the-binary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I think it is there for the sake of data since binary in general is used for some form of data. If you look at an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) you'll see that it is tab, acknowledgement, line feed. As a programmer this doesn't seem like anything to me but I'm not the most experienced. If you read it vertical then it is enquiry, start of text, end of text, end of transmission. This seems more reasonable seeing as it's some form of data. But..it could also be random. If you look at the other achievement **A Real Cluster....** it has the same picture but with more binary digits.

Going off of what they are saying in the comments...

#### Horizontal

- Decimal: 2410
- Hex: 96A
- Bits: 12

Tab, acknowledgement, line feed

#### Vertical

Left to Right

- Decimal: 2716
- Hex: A9C
- Bits: 12

Right to Left:

- Decimal: 2261
- Hex: 8D5
- Bits: 12

Enquiry, start of text, end of text, end transmission

---

In response to Patrick, Yes, ASCII contains 8 bits per character, not 4.  I assumed each row/column of data was in itself a complete set (with 0s).  Now if we assume there isn't 0s for all of them then we can try this...

```
0000|1001 0110|1010

  0    9   6    A
```

or 0x09 and 0x6A which is -> tab, j ...not much

How about vertical?

Left to Right:

```
0000|1010 1001|1100 

  0   A    9   C
```

or 0x0A and 0x9C which is -> line feed, doesn't exist on ascii

Right to Left

```
0000|1000 1101|0101

  0    8    D   5
```

or 0x08 and 0xD5 which is -> backspace, doesn't exist on ascii

None of that seemed helpful.  Next I try to google 96A and came up with chinese tanks.  Is that a thing in Saint Row?  Next A9C and came across some form of aviation (planes).  Next and finally 8D5.  I came across hats.  What if I added a 0 in front of each one?  Different results again.  There is a lot of different combinations of things and it seems like it would take a while to figure it out unless we got lucky.

How about the actual digits? 9-6-10.  Is that anything?  How about Corinthians 9:6-10..

> Remember this: Whoever sows sparingly will also reap sparingly, and whoever sows generously will also reap generously. 7 Each of you should give what you have decided in your heart to give, not reluctantly or under compulsion, for God loves a cheerful giver. 8 And God is able to bless you abundantly, so that in all things at all times, having all that you need, you will abound in every good work. 9 As it is written: “They have freely scattered their gifts to the poor; their righteousness endures forever.” 10 Now he who supplies seed to the sower and bread for food will also supply and increase your store of seed and will enlarge the harvest of your righteousness.

This seem familiar?  Like I said..many things.  Could be a date.  September 6th, 2010. I did some research on release dates and didn't come across anything.  Maybe something in the game has to do with it? Or something in the game has to do with an event that happened on that day.  I have plenty of theory's for this but I am going to stop here.  I hope this gets peoples brains going at max speed :)

**EDIT:**

Just adding this edit real quick before I go to bed. Since I do not know much about the game I will need some confirmation but is there anything to do with the night time?  Because going off of one of my theory's (the date) I came across [Laylat al-Qadr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laylat_al-Qadr) which is "Night Of Power".  just a thought.

Comment: This is actually useful just for pointing out the other achievement picture.

Comment: Yep. Plus the fact that Cody mentioned that the text is Enquiry based, start of text, end of text, end transmission. Could this be part of it, some how?

Comment: @warrenwoodhouse it seems unlikely that it was random for that to be in there because it makes sense to an extent but I guess it is quite possible.  It seems like too good of an opportunity to make it random.

Comment: Typically ASCII contains 8 bits per character, not 4, but interesting interpretation.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts added edit 2 for you :)

Answer (score 7):

**It's likely just some random binary to express the concept of a "data cluster".**

There is another achievement for finding all the clusters, called "[A Real Cluster](http://www.xboxachievements.com/game/saints-row-4/achievement/80183-A-Real-Cluster----.html)". It has a similar image, seen here side-by-side with the one in the question:

[image: A Real Cluster] [image: Oh, a piece of candy]

As you can see, the greater achievement has the same binary sequence, but embedded in a wider field of binary. Notably, this binary field extends beyond the edges of the image, meaning we can't know the whole thing.

Additionally, the highlighting of certain digits adds an additional level of information. We have 0, 1, highlighted 0, highlighted 1. That's [quaternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternary_numeral_system), which is a base-4 system. Given that there aren't any common ways to interpret quaternary, I view this as additional evidence that the sequence has no real meaning.

Given this, I doubt that the specific sequence has an important meaning.

---

But, for completeness, here are some possible interpretations of that sequence:

1001, 0110, 1010 = 9, 6, 10
100101101010 = 2410 = 96A (hex)

Looking at just the highlighted numbers, we have:

1011100 = 92

Since the digits are not in a fixed-width font, I doubt that we are supposed to interpret the data as vertical columns.

Comment: Thanks mate, you pretty much answered my question. Do Data Clusters even exist in the real world, just completely out of context?

Comment: @warrenwoodhouse I don't know the details of the "data clusters" in the game, so I can't speak to the existence of anything closely matching that, but in general a data cluster is just that, a cluster of data. Strictly speaking, this comment is a data cluster. Here's a wikipedia article on data clusters: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cluster, as they appear in computer memory.

Comment: @warrenwoodhouse If you think it's helpful, please upvote. You can accept an answer at some point as well, although we generally recommend you wait at least a day or two to allow more people a chance to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snapshot of the same code on another screen. `1 00 11 10 0`. Eight digits, but not quite in 8-digit binary. It's the same hilighted sequence that you see in the other pics. If you convert each part to decimal, you get `1 0 3 2 0`. I don't know of any significance that might be in the game, but maybe someone else might know. Perhaps a date: 1/03/20 or 10/3/20.

Comment: Ah. Found something after typing “Saints Row 4 2010 March”, assuming the 10/03 is formatted as YY/MM, according to Wikipedia, Saints Row was released on the PSP in that month. Interesting, but I’m sure it could be just coincidental.